# Android App Memory Usage Issue

Tags: android, memory-management, emulation

I have been developing a simple memory game app and I tested it on my phone ,LG V20, for the first time today. However, when I ran it on my phone the android profiler showed ungodly amounts of memory being used resulting in the app crashing at certain transition points, and I have no idea why.This shows the app opening and the opening animation,the second hump, and the homepage itself,the opening animation just has the thought bubbles fade in one at a time
[image: Imgur]
[image]
[image]
**And then the same part running on an emulated Nexus 5X** [image]
Then traversing through the activities, on the physical V20
[image]
And on the emulator
[image]
And Here's what each of those activities looks like, level_select
[image]
S1L1
[image]
This is my first app so I am aware that is not very well optimized and even the lower number on the emulator is pretty high. However, I'm just very confused as to why the app is taking up roughly 5 times as much memory at points on the phyiscal phone versus the emulator. And also why the emulator doesn't show any memory being used by graphics. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents on this. Different phones have different resolutions and hence have different memory consumptions. There are a few things that you can do to make sure your application doesn't result in out of memory exception

1. Make sure you use Glide, Picasso or any other image loading library to load images in your application. Loading images directly or through layouts results in sudden spikes in memory consumption
2. If you are using animations, make sure you clean them up after you exit the animations specially if they involve infinite repetitions.
3. Try to use smaller images. One possible way is to convert .jpg and .png to .webp which are considerably smaller in size.
4. Take a memory dump using Android Studio and see if there are any memory leaks present in your application. There are many articles available online to guide you through that. For e.g [link](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8)
5. AsyncTasks are many times responsible for causing context memory leaks. Try not to have context inside an asynctask or if you do, make sure its available to for the GC to collect at the end of operation
6. Even if the memory leak is very small it adds up and eventually causes out of memory exceptions.

Furthermore you can search for OutOfMemory or memory leaks to get more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will look into those things! I just have a question about number 1. Right now I have all of my images in the drawable folder and am loading them from their, would I have to host all of the images on something like imgur to be able to load them through Glide or Picasso. I'm not really sure what you mean by this if you could clarify a bit I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No you would keep them in the drawable folder but instead of directly putting them as `<image_view>.setImageDrawable` or directly in the xml layout, you would use the Glide library to load it programmatically from the activity

Comment: You would use something like `Glide.with(<activity>).load(<drawable>).into(<image_view>);`

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 phones (Nexus 5X and LG V20) have different resolutions, meaning that they will use different resources (I believe XXHDPI vs XXXHDPI).

If you are using a lot of images in your app, loading a lot of higher resolution images could cause that difference.

Try an emulator with the same resolution as your phone to see if this is causing your issue or try the make all the images smaller.